# Using anchor tag send id to next page in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am showing a html  table which is retrieving the data from mysql using php,the table has a column feedback, the elements in this column are hyperlinked, they direct you to program called feedback.php where a feedback form is there with candidate name and id retrieved from database and shown there , below is the code showing the data displayed on table page

```
echo " <header class='w3-container w3-black'>
      <h1>TABLE Of Faculty Position Applicants :-</h1>
    </header>
     <form action = '' method = 'post'>   
    <table class ='w3-table w3-striped w3-border'>
    <tr class ='w3-grey'>
    <th>Candidate No </th><th>Candidate Name</th><th>Google Scholar</th><th>DBLP</th><th>CV</th><th>Feedback</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['candidate_no'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['candidate_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=" . $row['gs_link'] . " target='_blank'>Google Scholar</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href=" . $row['dblp_link'] . " target='_blank'>DBLP link</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href=" . $row['cv_link'] . " target='_blank'>CV</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href=" . $row['feedback_link'] ."  id = ".$row[id]. "  target='_blank'>Feedback</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
```

now you can see this line :-

```
echo "<td><a href=" . $row['feedback_link'] ."  id = ".$row[id]. "  target='_blank'>Feedback</a></td>";
```

which I am using to pass the id to feedback.php

on feedback.php this query is written  which requires id and retrieved id of the specific candidate using id which is passed to this page

```
$query="SELECT candidate_name FROM faculty WHERE id=$_POST[id]";
$query2="SELECT candidate_no FROM faculty WHERE id=$_POST[id]";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
$row=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$row2=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
$conn->close();
```

I want to know the way to pass id to feedback.php so that I can retrieve candidate name and id on that program and show it in form which I will display because in above program I am doing some mistakes or is using wrong way to pass the id to feedback.php , please help me if there is problem I will clarify , help me.

Comment: just replace one line echo "<td><a href=" . $row['feedback_link'] ."  id = ".$row[id]. "  target='_blank'>Feedback</a></td>"; to echo "<td><a href='" . $row['feedback_link'] ."'  id = '".$row[id]. "'  target='_blank'>Feedback</a></td>";

Comment: not working showing same error as it did earlier :- Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'

Comment: Could you add the html output of the feedback_link? And i think you may need to use $_GET params in your feedback.php. When you use href you're not using the POST http method but the GET http method.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/c3f63g

Comment: also i am using $_GET[id] now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the id as a `GET` variable, making a link something like this:

```
feedback.php?id=123
```

Then on `feedback.php` you can catch the ID by using `$_GET['id']` where `id` is the name of the variable and the return will be whatever is set in it, in our example it will be ID 123.

You can then run your query on these IDs.

Comment: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' , this error is coming

Comment: Have you set a correct ID, and the link generated is has a valid ID in it?

Comment: the id is retrieved from database and that id is passed to feedback.php using get as u have suggested. this query is using that id $query="SELECT candidate_name FROM faculty WHERE id=$_GET[id]";

Comment: `"SELECT candidate_name FROM faculty WHERE id="'$_GET[id]'";` The PHP variable is not part of your query, but it's value is. You need to use the proper quote marks to ensure the ID value is sent in your query.

Comment: `"SELECT candidate_name FROM faculty WHERE id=".$_GET[id];` Try this

Comment: I made another variable and put $_GET[id] in that variable and then tried to echo it to see if the variable is passed or not but nothing is happening means its not passing , I tried to echo $_GET['id']  too but error is coming

Comment: Then your URI does not have the GET variable. Does your URL have `?id=` in it?

Answer (score 0):

Use hyperlink queries.

```
 http://mywebsite?data=test
           server.       Queries
```

You can access them easily in php:

```
<?php
$data=$_GET["data"]
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use $_GET instead of $_POST

```
$query="SELECT candidate_name FROM faculty WHERE id=$_GET['id']";
$query2="SELECT candidate_no FROM faculty WHERE id=$_GET['id']";
```

Comment: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id , this error is coming